# Compact Framework in WinCE and performance

Tags: performance, compact-framework, windows-ce

Anyone know relative performance hit for using the full as opposed to compact WinCE framework? We are contemplating using the full to get the ability to do drag and drop, etc. but not if it's a huge hit to processing ability. Any guesstimates about the difference? Uses x% more processor?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but isn't .NET CF implemented as a stack based VM? Apparently Dalvik (the VM used in Android) is a register based VM which is more suited to ARM based RISC architectures?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an average indicator on the Full vs Compact Framework performance.

It depends on the code and classes you use. The implementation of a lot of methods is just different, but most of the times the full framework implements more code that runs better because does not have to struggle with WinCE limitations.